# Convert array of rings to geoJSON object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, arcgis, arcgis-js-api

I have an array of rings that I am working with and I am trying to convert it to geoJSON:

```
[
    [
        -13441425.32511117,
        4491520.711015136
    ],
    [
        -13440894.1920939,
        4491511.685098792
    ],
    [
        -13440922.71925878,
        4490494.010447212
    ],
    [
        -13441438.25014971,
        4490494.010447212
    ],
    [
        -13441425.32511117,
        4491520.711015136
    ]
]
```

It seems like I should be able to do this relatively simply using the [ArcGIS Geometry class](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-geometry-Geometry.html#toJSON), but I haven't been able to get it to work. For example, I tried creating a new Geometry instance and then adding the rings to it but I don't understand how to then call the toJSON method on it after I add the ring data. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I haven't yet used this API yet but according to the docs, it's the [Polygon](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-geometry-Polygon.html) subclass that allows defining rings. Have you tried creating a Polygon, instantiating it with this JSON input as the `rings` property and then call its `.toJSON` method?

Comment: I have tried to instantiate but I don't think I'm doing it correctly:
` 
const polygonGeom = new Geometry({
  rings: event.graphic.geometry.rings
})

polygonGeom.toJSON()
`

Any ideas?

Comment: @Attila - oh I think i misinterpreted your response. I looked at the polygon class. Are you recommending something like:

`const rings = [
 [  // first ring
  [-97.06138,32.837,35.1,4.8],
  [-97.06133,32.836,35.2,4.1],
  [-97.06124,32.834,35.3,4.2],
  [-97.06138,32.837,35.1,4.8]  // same as first vertex
 ], [  // second ring
  [-97.06326,32.759,35.4],
  [-97.06298,32.755,35.5],
  [-97.06153,32.749,35.6],
  [-97.06326,32.759,35.4]  // same as first vertex
 ]
];

const polygon = new Polygon({
  rings: rings,
  spatialReference: { wkid: 4326 }
});`
then:
polygon.toJson() ?

Comment: yes. I haven't tried it myself but according to the doc it should work.

Comment: Thanks Attila, this worked to convert it to JSON. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

To put a bit more light on the subject feeling it could help other readers.

Don't confuse GeoJSON (1) with ESRI JSON. Although both are formats to encode geographic features, the first one is define by IETF and the second by ESRI so we are talking about different formats.

One important difference to highlight is that GeoJSON coordinates are expressed using a geographic coordinate system based on WGS84 datum (2), while in ESRI JSON coordinates could be expressed in any system.

ArcGIS JavaScript API methods `toJSON` and `fromJSON` uses ESRI JSON.

In ESRI JSON a Polygon is defined by, a spatial reference, and an array of rings (or curved rings) (3). A ring is defined by an array of points where, the first and last are equal, and has at least four elements (three point).

Any polygon (that is not the empty polygon) should have at least one ring, the exterior ring, where points are clockwise oriented. If a polygon has more than one ring, then it has holes, holes points are counter-clockwise oriented, that differ them from the exterior ring.

Finally as mention in the comments, to create a Polygon with an array of rings you just pass it to the constructor (4),

```
const rings = [
 [  // first ring
  [-97.06138,32.837],
  [-97.06133,32.836],
  [-97.06124,32.834],
  [-97.06138,32.837]  // same as first vertex
 ], [  // second ring
  [-97.06326,32.759],
  [-97.06298,32.755],
  [-97.06153,32.749],
  [-97.06326,32.759]  // same as first vertex
 ]
];

const polygon = new Polygon({
  rings: rings,
  spatialReference: { wkid: 4326 }
});
```

1. https://geojson.org
2. https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7946#section-4
3. https://developers.arcgis.com/documentation/common-data-types/geometry-objects.htm
4. https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-geometry-Polygon.html#properties-summary

Comment: Thank you so much. This has really helped me understand the difference between GeoJSON vs ESRI JSON. Appreciate it!